# Sorting mongo db collection by date inside array object

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, find

i'm trying to query a collection and sort it by this:
first i get all documents that match an array of string, then i must SORT them by rating property and then when i have two documents with the same rate i must SORT them by the last comment's date.

I'll try to be more clear ,

here's a json example of a document in the collection :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5703decca27819000000"),
"__v" : 0,
"tokens" : null,
"comments" : [ 
    {
        "owner" : "name.surname",
        "created" : ISODate("2016-05-02T18:44:38.000Z"),
        "comment" : "RA visto da posta"
    }, 
    {
        "owner" : "name.surname",
        "created" : ISODate("2016-05-02T18:44:38.000Z"),
        "comment" : "visto "
    }
],
"attachments" : [],
"status" : {
    "tag" : "tp.st.resource.edited",
    "owner" : "name.surname",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-05-03T07:25:55.000Z"),
    "visibility" : [ 
        "recruiter", 
        "hunter"
    ],
    "extra" : null,
    "rating" : 4
},
"order" : 70020160503.0,
"zone" : "",
"letter" : "",
"created" : ISODate("2016-04-05T15:50:36.000Z"),
"phones" : [ 
    {
        "number" : "555555555",
        "type" : "main"
    }
],
"email" : "email@email.com",
"profileType" : "Tecnico/Sistemista/Windows",
"skills" : [ 
    {
        "id" : 39,
        "value" : 2,
        "name" : "SQL"
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 79,
        "value" : 2,
        "name" : "Oracle"
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 80,
        "value" : 3,
        "name" : "Access"
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 89,
        "value" : 2,
        "name" : "SQLite"
    }, 
    {
        "id" : 127,
        "value" : 3,
        "name" : "Windows"
    }
],
"webSites" : [],
"birth" : {
    "date" : ISODate("1962-06-19T22:00:00.000Z"),
    "place" : null
},
"surname" : "John",
"name" : "Doe"
```

}

So my query by far is this :

db.getCollection('resources').find({'skills.name': { $all: ["Java", "Python"] }}).sort({'status.rating' : -1})

Now i have all the 'resources' that have a skill among "Java" and "Python" sorted by status.rating. Now i need to sort them by last comment's date.

Anyone willing to help?

Comment: Try `db.getCollection('resources').find({'skills.name': { $all: ["Java", "Python"] }}).sort({'status.rating' : -1, "comments.created":-1})`

Comment: This is not what i'm looking for, i need to sort the results by the LATEST comments date..

Comment: That is what it does. Have you tried the query ? What is your mongo version ? It should sort by max created time in comments array. It sorts the main documents not the array.

Comment: I'll try to explain myself better.
Let's pretend i have a two documents:

Document A with status.rating 5 and with two comments, one created on 10 october 2017 and one created on 12 November 2017.

Documnet B with status.rating 5 and with one comment created on 1 December 2017.

The query should return Document B and then Document A but document B must comes first because he has a comment created later than every other comment in Document A.

So i think i should compare the last entry on comments array ( because it will be the latest comment for that rdocument) with all documents..

Comment: Yes that is exactly what the query should do. It compares the latest(max) dates in a array element across documents for descending option unless i' m missing something and sorts the document. I'll test it out when I have some time. Look [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4346)

Comment: Yes, i've tested it and it works !

Thank you very much, saved my day!